# New project in laravel give problem with routes

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have created a new laravel project and added a simple controller with a method.

Then in my api.php file. I added this line to call the controller.

```
Route::get("test", "ApiTestController@test");
```

My problem is when I call this api from the postman I am getting "Object not found!" error.

My url in postman is like this:

http://localhost/my-project/api/test

My htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Do I have to make any change to the configuration?

Comment: have you setup the .htaccess properly?

Comment: Yes I have htacess

Comment: yes you have but is it working? means does apache2 configuration setup properly to run the `.htaccess` and is `modrewrite` module enabled?

Comment: i don't think you need to make any changes in .htaccess for that. As I see your URL, You might need to user "public" in between "api" & "test".  
Try URL like "http://localhost/my-project/public/api/test" OR Try run php artisan serve in terminal at project folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing **public** in your URL. Check with this URL you'll get you API data.

http://localhost/my-project/public/api/test

If you want to remove public from URL then.

1. **with htaccess.**

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now you should be able to access the website without the “/public/index.php/” part.

2. **with server file.**

   - Rename `server.php` in your Laravel root folder to `index.php`
   - Copy the `.htaccess` file from `/public` directory to your Laravel root folder.

Comment: Yes this worked for me.. can you help me configure with 
public" required in the url